# Exclude paths from URL with split and merge or regex replace

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, extract

My plan is to alter a URL and remove some of the paths. For instance, from this: site = `"link.com/path1/path2/path3/random"` I want to get this: `"link.com/path1/path3/random"` only if `path2` exists. `path2` might have slightly different name (e.g. `path2_version1`, `path2_version2` etc)

My solution works below. I actually, get all the paths separately and then merge them:

```
    import re
    from urllib.parse import urljoin
    import urllib.request
    import os
    import csv

    site = "https://img.mysite.com/c_fill,g_auto,w_750,h_536/q_auto,f_auto/mysitecom/2020/05/06/w331e4787162_5/my-image-saved"

def image_graber(old_url):
    url_main = 'https://img.mysite.com/mysitecom/'

    split_url_paths = old_url.rsplit('/', 6)
    url_subfolder1 = split_url_paths[2]
    url_subfolder2 = split_url_paths[3]
    url_subfolder3 = split_url_paths[4]
    url_subfolder4 = split_url_paths[5]
    url_subfolder5 = split_url_paths[6]

    final_url = url_main + '/' + url_subfolder1 + '/' + url_subfolder2 + '/' + url_subfolder3 + '/' + url_subfolder4 + '/' + url_subfolder5 

    urllib.request.urlretrieve(final_url, "C:\My Site\IMG\/"+os.path.basename(final_url))


image_graber(site)
```

I tried changing the script to make it more professional. In this case one `urljoin` couldn't work as it can take max 3 paths. So, I used more than one but to my surprise it doesn't work as it should:

```
#This didn't work
url_join1 = urljoin(url_main, url_subfolder1, url_subfolder2)
print(url_join1)
url_join2 = urljoin(url_join1, url_subfolder3, url_subfolder4)
print(url_join2)
final_join = urljoin(url_join2, url_subfolder5)
print(final_join)
```

My question is, why this didn't work above? A possibly easier and faster way to just extract this part using regex was also tested:

```
if('c_fill' or 'q_auto' in site):
    exclude_path1 = re.sub(r'/c_fill[^/]+/',r'/',site)
    exclude_path2 = re.sub(r'/q_auto[^/]+/',r'/',exclude_path1)
    print(exclude_path2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample old url:

```
old_url = 'https://img.mysite.com/c_fill,g_auto,w_750,h_536/alsothis/q_auto,f_auto/mysitecom/2020/05/06/deletethis/w331e4787162_5/my-image-saved'
```

Now you can simply split it by '/' and make a list:

```
splitted = old_url.split('/')
```

Also, create unwanted or stuff to delete

```
delete = ['alsothis','w331e4787162_5', 'deletethis']
```

Now you can do a quick list comprehension to get your final url.

```
res = '/'.join([x for x in splitted if x not in delete])
```

res will give you the required output.